# Get width and height of container from view

Tags: ios, xcode, container-view

Forgive me if this is a duplicate. I thought for sure this would be an obvious question.

I have a container in a storyboard, which is of class ModelViewController (the whole view controller). From ModelViewController I need to get the width and height of the container. I am currently trying:

```
self.view.bounds.size
```

Which yields 0.563380 and 0.000000. I also tried

```
self.view.frame.size
```

Which yields the dimensions of the entire screen. What am I missing here?

Comment: `self.view.bounds.size.height` & `self.view.bounds.size.width`.

Comment: From the interface builder the dimensions are 320 x 250. This is what I am expecting.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm using to get the respective width and height. (Yields the above results) Just thought I'd save some typing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384696/view-controller-frame-size-in-child-controller)

> View frames are not actually useable in viewDidLoad; you should move all of your geometry-manipulating code into viewWillAppear. The system will clobber any changes you set in viewDidLoad between there and when it's about tom come on screen.

And the comment

> Actually, you should move geometry changes to -viewDidAppear pre-iOS 5 and to -viewWillLayoutSubviews for iOS 5+. -viewWillAppear: may not actually have the correct bounds/orientation if the view is being animated.

I found the solution. The correct dimensions are indeed given when called from `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. I was calling from `viewDidLoad` giving incorrect results.